# PHP $_SERVER array returns literally 1

Tags: php, debugging

About a week ago I got an odd request on my server. I don't have the details immediately available though the issue *this question is about* is part of the debugging process.

I setup my server to email me the following detail when the issue occurred again:

```
mail('user@domain.tld','Domain Path Error Debug ',print_r($d)."\n\n\n".print_r($_SERVER));
```

I received the following email body:

> 1
>
> 1

Well, *that* is not what I was expecting!

So for the moment I added a second line however I know that the second parameter is only required when using `echo` which an email message is not:

```
mail('user@domain.tld','Domain Path Error Debug ',print_r($d,1)."\n\n\n".print_r($_SERVER,1));
```

That being said, is there any legitimate reason why the `print_r($_SERVER)` would only output as `1`? Obviously *no* - I have no reason to overwrite the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: You want `implode` not `print_r`.

Comment: "_however I know that the second parameter is only required when using echo_" That doesn't sound quite right. It's not only `echo` but _any_ function that takes a string as parameter - which `mail` does.

Comment: I don't know what your setup is, if they changed something in the behaviour of `print_r` - fact is the code you have been using successfully for years doesn't work any longer and I was trying to help, not nag. Announcing "_This doesn't answer the question_" but then using the solution to overcome your problem isn't great behaviour in my eyes. If you can't appreciate people trying to help you I'm sorry. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

From the [print_​r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) PHP manual:

"*If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to true, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.*"

Also: "*When the return parameter is true, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is true.*"

So set the second parameter of `print_r` to true to return the results:

```
mail('user@domain.tld','Domain Path Error Debug ',print_r($d, true)."\n\n\n".print_r($_SERVER, true));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It doesn't? "_Otherwise, the return value is true._" sounds like that's why you get "1"s in your mail.